# Django websockets auth

Tags: django, tornado, sockjs

I use tornado + sockjs for websockets and Django rest framework for main app.
Also I use rest-framework-jwt for auth on Django app.
Now I have to determine user in tornado. How I see it:

1. User send jwt in message when sockjs connected to tornado server.
2. Tornado server parse jwt and determine is valid jwt or not? But for this solution I have to read database. But this operation is sync which is not good, because tornado is async.

Also I thought use Celery. When user connected to tornado, tornado creats task for celery and in this task jwt will be parsed. In that case solution is not blocking tornado. But how then to notice user via websockets about check jwt?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**:

You shouldn't need to read database to validate a JWT. JWT is a signed token, all you need is the secret key to validate the JWT.

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

(**Note:** The diagram below is rather redundant for JWT, as a JWT is already a signed token and can be validated without needing to be saved anywhere. This diagram, however, works for cookie based auth.)

You can share auth tokens between Django and Tornado using a message broker (such as Redis):

[image: Share auth token between Django and Tornado]

Redis is fast and lightweight and you can connect with it asynchronously from Tornado.

There's no need for Celery here.

Comment: I thought about Redis. But Redis is not assync?

Comment: @Mike You can connect with Redis using an async driver.

Comment: But JWT token will be expired, how in that case check it?

Answer (score 1):

If will you use SQLAlchemy, to connect and handler database, you could use tornado-sqlalchemy to make the async query on the database and notify your user via WebSocket without break event loop of the tornado.

```
@coroutine
def open(self):
   with self.make_session() as session:
       jtw = request.params.get('authorization')
       jwt_valid = yield self.check_jwt_valid(jwt, session)
       if not jwt_valid:
          self.write('JWT Inválid')
          self.close()      

@coroutine 
def check_jwt_valid(self, jwt, session):
   jwt_found = session.query(JWT_QUERY...).first()
   return jwt_found
```

Comment: Maybe, but I want to use method from rest-framework-jwt. Because if I want to change auth method so I just call another method instead of read from database again. I think use one method for one task is better solution than makes severals method (for sync, for async etc).